# Doctrine2 mixing YAML entities with ANNOTATION Traits doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have some entities which uses my `SluggableTrait`, which contains `name` and `slug` fields along it's methods.

```
trait SluggableTrait
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"}, updatable=false))
     */
    private $slug;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return SluggableTrait
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     *
     * @return SluggableTrait
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName() ? $this->getName() : 'n/a';
    }

    public function getClassName()
    {
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        return $reflect->getShortName();
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to use it in a YAML mapped entity, database won't create it's fields...

Let's say I have `Foo` class

```
class Foo
{
    use SluggableTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

With the YAML mapping

```
Utils\DoctrineBundle\Entity\Foo:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

When updating my schema (even creating a new empty database) my `foo` table will only have `id` field, `name` and `slug` doesn't exists.

Everything works fine if I use annotation in both items, the Trait and the Class. If mixed mapping, doesn't work.

When using YAML mapping in my trait, just to give it a try I get this error whenever I try to update my schema

> [2015-12-07 13:20:33] app.ERROR:
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class
>   'Utils\DoctrineBundle\Entity\SluggableTrait' does not exist (uncaught
>   exception) at
>   /srv/myapp/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php
>   line 96 while running console command `doctrine:schema:update`
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException(code: 0):
>   Class 'Utils\DoctrineBundle\Entity\SluggableTrait' does not exist
>   at
>   /srv/myapp/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96)"}
>
> ```
>                                                                                [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
> ```
>
> Class 'Utils\DoctrineBundle\Entity\SluggableTrait' does not exist
>
> doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em
>   [EM]]

I've tried to search for a Trait YAML example without success... So I'm stuck right now.

Well, after some tests, Doctrine doesn't allow you to mix YAML and ANOTTATION without redeclaring properties which obviously is what we want to avoid using a Trait (and extending a Class)

I've created a PR in order to follow this
https://github.com/doctrine/common/pull/701

This PR allows you to use YAML mapped traits, but doesn't trigger some events so it needs to go deeper.

Comment: Shouldn't you be ORM annotating your Foo class with `@ORM/Entity()` and `@ORM/Table(name="foo")`?

Comment: isn't necessary, Doctrine will generate your table name as your class name. But actually in my code I have `@ORM/Table(name="foo")` I just didn't write here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

You can't mix YAML and Annotation mappings and Traits doesn't work with YAML mappings.