# Add column mappings to an extended class in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a PHP entity that inherits from a base class contained in a library which I cannot change. I would like to map properties that are inherited from the base class to database columns. Since the `@Column` annotation must be used on a field of method, I can not define the inherited columns that way. Using `@AttributeOverrides` also will not work as then I would need to have access to the base class to make it a MappedSuperclass.

Example of classes:

```
class LibraryClass
{
    protected $someProperty;
}


/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="child")
 */
class Child extends LibraryClass
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="some_property", type="string")
     * Somehow target $this->someProperty
     */     
}
```

Is there any other way to map parent properties without transferring the properties between classes and not using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You could use mapping with XML or YML instead of annotations. It's documented here.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Comment: I would like to stick with annotation mappings for the other entities though, and that [doesn't seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272567/1871016).